# Html button call a function in code behind and it fires only once

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have html button which calls a function in code behind and it fires only once.

**I want it to fire event every time I click the button.**

It is possibly duplicated but I have tried to add "!IsPostBack" but it doesn't work.

My ascx class:

```
<button runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-report" onserverclick="OnReportBtnClick" id="reportBtn">                
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i>      
</button>
```

I have to use html button, not `<asp:Button>` because `<asp:Button>` doesn't let me to insert `<i>` tag inside.

Here is my code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            try
            {
                reportBtn.ServerClick += OnReportBtnClick;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }

//this method is called only once even I click the button many times afterwards.
    protected void OnReportBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Set file name 
            string pdfName = SPContext.Current.Web.Title + fileType;
            CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.MinValue;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(report_startDate_datePicker.Value))
                startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(report_startDate_datePicker.Value, format, provider);

            DateTime endDate = DateTime.MaxValue;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(report_endDate_datePicker.Value))
                endDate = DateTime.ParseExact(report_endDate_datePicker.Value, format, provider);
            // Provisioning data for report
            var report = GetReport(startDate, endDate);
            // Merger data to template html
            byte[] data = GetPdfData(htmlTemplate, report);
            //Respond report to client
            RenderResponse(pdfName, data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LoggingService.LogError(LoggingService.NTT_ERROR,
                string.Format("ERROR: {0} - SOURCE: {1} | {2}", ex.Message, ex.Source, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name));
        }
    }

//I think the problem could be this method.
//I return a pdf file to client
private void RenderResponse(string pdfName, byte[] data)
        {
            try
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + pdfName);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
                HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LoggingService.LogError(LoggingService.NTT_ERROR,
                    string.Format("ERROR: {0} - SOURCE: {1} | {2}", ex.Message, ex.Source, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name));
            }
```

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, the problem seems to be somewhere else...

Comment: Tested your code, it works just fine. And you don't need to assign the event on page_load when you already specify `onserverclick` in the aspx

Comment: My stuff is to return a pdf file to download in client side. Please take a look at my updated code.

Comment: What do the error logs say?

Comment: No, it doesn't have any error. The problem is that the event button click is fired only once. After the event is fired the first time, I continue to click the button, but the event is not fired anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinkButton

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="ReportBtn" Text="<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk'></i>" OnClick="ReportBtn_Click" CssClass="btn btn-report" />
```

in .cs page

```
protected void ReportBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//your code
}
```

They do support html in the text field.

Comment: please help the event firing first. Thanks in advanced.